# What’s the time complexity of the this function with a nested 'for' loop?

Tags: algorithm, analysis

Consider:

```
bar (a) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
      a = a * (i + j);

  return a;
}
```

Find the [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) for the above function.

Comment: This is an ***exact*** duplicate of *[How can I find the time complexity of an algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-can-i-find-the-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm/33474486#33474486)* as [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-can-i-find-the-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm/33474486#33474486) covers it. Or in other words, the answer could have been found by reading that answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the time complexity of an algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-can-i-find-the-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is `O(n^2)`.
Since the inner for loop runs from 0 to i and outer for loop runs from 0 to n it follows the pattern `1 + 2 + ... + n` and this sums up to `n*(n-1)/2`, which in turn is `O(n^2)`